# Python - where is element added when using set.add()

Tags: python, set, element, addition

I find that when I use the add function of a set structure of python, the element seems to be added in a position I can't figure out.

```
>>> a=set([(0, 2)])
>>> a.add((0,4))
>>> a
set([(0, 2), (0, 4)])
>>> a.add((1,0))
>>> a
set([(1, 0), (0, 2), (0, 4)])
>>> a.add((2,5))
>>> a
set([(2, 5), (1, 0), (0, 2), (0, 4)])
>>> a.add((3,0))
>>> a
set([(3, 0), (2, 5), (1, 0), (0, 2), (0, 4)])
>>> a.add((1,6))
>>> a
set([(3, 0), (0, 2), (1, 6), (0, 4), (2, 5), (1, 0)])
```

As can be seen, sometimes the element is added at the beginning and at other times, at the end or in the middle. In the last example, existing elements were reordered as well.

Any idea of how the insertion occurs?

Comment: this [video](http://blip.tv/pycon-us-videos-2009-2010-2011/pycon-2010-the-mighty-dictionary-55-3352147) is a must watch.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sets are unordered.  The notion of "where" an element is in a set is undefined.

Answer (score 4):

The sets in python are orderless. The order is arbitrary.

Comment: Not random. The elements are hashed, and the set is built upon a hash table based on these hashes

Comment: "apparently random," or, correlated with something you can't see.

Comment: What do you people here in SO when you amend your answer due to someone else's comment? It is correct to leave it as it was before?

Comment: @thikonom SO makes mention that the post was edited, if someone amends your answer and you agree, it is fair to edit!

Answer (score 1):

Sets use the same hash function as dicts to add elements. Indeed, they are just dict without the value element.

[This video](http://blip.tv/pycon-us-videos-2009-2010-2011/pycon-2010-the-mighty-dictionary-55-3352147) may help you understand it better.

If you use integers, sets are ordered (to a 'human' sense of sorted):

```
>>> s=set()
>>> for e in range(10):
...    s.add(e)
...    print s
... 
set([0])
set([0, 1])
set([0, 1, 2])
set([0, 1, 2, 3])
set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

But if you use a tuple, they are not 'ordered' to human eyes:

```
>>> s=set()
>>> for t in ((i,i*i) for i in range(10)):
...    s.add(t)
...    print s
... 
set([(0, 0)])
set([(0, 0), (1, 1)])
set([(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 4)])
set([(3, 9), (0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 4)])
set([(3, 9), (0, 0), (1, 1), (4, 16), (2, 4)])
set([(0, 0), (4, 16), (5, 25), (3, 9), (2, 4), (1, 1)])
set([(6, 36), (0, 0), (4, 16), (5, 25), (3, 9), (2, 4), (1, 1)])
set([(6, 36), (0, 0), (7, 49), (4, 16), (5, 25), (3, 9), (2, 4), (1, 1)])
set([(6, 36), (0, 0), (7, 49), (4, 16), (5, 25), (3, 9), (2, 4), (1, 1), (8, 64)])
set([(6, 36), (0, 0), (7, 49), (4, 16), (5, 25), (3, 9), (9, 81), (2, 4), (1, 1), (8, 64)])
```

Now try these two lines in the interpreter:

```
>>> dict.fromkeys(range(10),None)
{0: None, 1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: None, 5: None, 6: None, 7: None, 8: None, 9: None}
>>> dict.fromkeys(((i,i*i) for i in range(10)),None)
{(6, 36): None, (0, 0): None, (7, 49): None, (4, 16): None, (5, 25): None, (3, 9): None, (9, 81): None, (2, 4): None, (1, 1): None, (8, 64): None}
```

You can see the dict produced is the same 'order' as the set example.

While dicts and set with ONLY int keys *may* be 'ordered', from a practical point of view, **dicts and set have no order.**

If you watch the linked video, you will understand why.

Answer (score 1):

The element goes to a particular spot in the hash table according to its hash value. For elements with same last 3 bits, collision occurs and some other spot is chosen for it. Hash table expands as soon it becomes 2/3rd full to decrease the collision rate.
see this [video](http://blip.tv/pycon-us-videos-2009-2010-2011/pycon-2010-the-mighty-dictionary-55-3352147) on hash tables.

```
>>> def bits(n):
    n+=2**32
    return bin(n)[-32:]

>>> bits(hash('a'))
'11100100000011011011000111100000' #last three bits are picked to determine the spot in hash table
>>> bits(hash('b'))
'11101011101011101101001101100011'
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers have said:

- sets are supposed to act like they have no order
- the actual mechanism for adding things to sets is the same as for dictionaries; sets are basically dictionaries of keys without items
- dictionaries are based on hash tables (for more on this: [What is the true difference between a dictionary and a hash table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061222/what-is-the-true-difference-between-a-dictionary-and-a-hash-table))

I thought it might be useful to see what's going on behind the scenes, so I commented up the actual source code for set's `add()` method (sorry for the scrolling).

```
def add(self, element):
    """Add an element to a set.

    This has no effect if the element is already present.
    """
    try:
        self._data[element] = True                             # self._data is the dictionary where all of the set elements are stored
    except TypeError:                                          # this try...except block catches the cases when element cannot be a dict key (that is, it isn't hashable)
        transform = getattr(element, "__as_immutable__", None) # the getattr() call is the same as trying to get element.__as_immutable__ and returning None if element doesn't have __as_immutable__
        if transform is None:                                     
            raise # re-raise the TypeError exception we caught # if we get to this line, then the element has no defined way to make it immutable (and thus hashable), so a TypeError is raised
        self._data[transform()] = True                         # so if we get here, transform() is the same as calling element.__as_immutable__() (which we know exists), and we can now add it to the self._data dict
```

As you can see, a set `add(element)` is the same as a dict `add(element)`, except it tries a little harder to hash `element`.