# find symmetric pairs using hash table(dictionary) in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, hashtable

I'm trying to get symmetric pairs with no duplicates, for example, from

```
L=[(1,3), (2,6), (3,5), (4,7), (5,3), (6,2), (3,4),(4,3)]
```

, I want to get like`[(2,6), (3,5), (3,4)]`, finding symmetric pairs.

this is my full code,

```
L=[(1,3), (2,6), (3,5), (4,7), (5,3), (6,2), (3,4),(4,3)]

def find_symmetric_pairs(L):
    temp = {}
    temp_list = []
    for i in L:
        key, value = i
        for j in L:
            key_j, value_j = j
            if key == value_j and value == key_j:
                temp_list.append(tuple((key,value)))
    return temp_list
```

and also, I'm trying to implement this function by using python hashtable, how can I use hashtable? 
The output looks like this

`[(2, 6), (3, 5), (5, 3), (6, 2), (3, 4), (4, 3)]`
but I want to show the output like above what I first told you...
`[(2,6), (3,5), (3,4)]`

Comment: You want to use a hash *table*? Why? You don't need a table, you just need a *set*.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add a check to see if the symmetric pair is already added to your result or not,

```
L=[(1,3), (2,6), (3,5), (4,7), (5,3), (6,2), (3,4),(4,3)]

res = set()

#Convert the list to a set
L = set(L)
# Iterate through the set
for t in L:
    # If the a tuple is present , and the reversed tuple is not in the result set already
    if (t[1], t[0]) in L and (t[1], t[0]) not in res:
        # Add it to result set
        res.add(t)

print(res)
```

The output will be

```
{(2, 6), (4, 3), (3, 5)}
```

Another approach is to reorder tuples so that first element is bigger then second, and count tuples via [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). The elements with count 2 will be the symmetric pairs

```
from collections import Counter

L=[(1,3), (2,6), (3,5), (4,7), (5,3), (6,2), (3,4),(4,3)]

#reorder tuple so that first element is bigger then second
L = [(t[1], t[0]) if t[0] < t[1] else t for t in L]

#Make a counter 
c = Counter(L)

#Count elements with count 2
res = [key for key, value in c.items() if value == 2]
print(res)
```

The output will be

```
[(6, 2), (5, 3), (4, 3)]
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no hash tables as such in Python, but you can use sets. The following combines the original set of tuples `set(L)` with a set of reversed tuples `{(y, x) for x, y in L}`. It later keeps only the pairs with the smaller first element:

```
pairs = set(L) & {(y, x) for x, y in L}
{(x,y) for x,y in pairs if x < y}
#{(2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5)}
```

Comment: @Aran-Fey The answer wasn't even correct, in the first place.

Comment: Wasn't it? I'm pretty sure it was. (I *did* think "this isn't correct, is it?!" at least 3 times in those 5 minutes though, before I finally understood what's going on)

Comment: @Aran-Fey It was correct by chance, just for this example.

Comment: "There are no hash tables as such in Python" I am decently sure ``dict`` is a hash table.

Comment: Actually this does have a minor bug (probably): If there are any symmetric tuples like `(1, 1)` in the input, they'll be included in the output even if they only occur once. Debatable if that's really a bug, but it's worth noting anyhow.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Dictionaries are implemented as hash tables but they are not called hash tables.

Comment: @Aran-Fey No, symmetric tuples will not be included (because of the condition `x<y`).

Comment: What hash tables are called does not change the fact that they do exist in Python. It seems like a very misleading statement.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi That's why I said "_as such_". Also, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2061406/4492932).

Comment: Python's ``dict`` specifically uses ``hash`` for its keys. As such, a *dictionary* might be any kind of mapping, but ``dict`` is a hashtable or at the very least functionally indistinguishable from one (in case someone wants to drag PyPy's JIT or strategies into this).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a set if you want to disregard order. Specifically a [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-frozenset) will allow you to hash and therefore use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
L_set_counter = Counter(map(frozenset, set(L)))
```

Now `L_set_counter` contains:

```
Counter({frozenset({2, 6}): 2, frozenset({3, 5}): 2, frozenset({3, 4}): 2, frozenset({1, 3}): 1, frozenset({4, 7}): 1})
```

And do find duplicates (`v==2` to make it more specific, this is more generic):

```
dups = {k for k, v in L_set_counter.items() if v > 1}
```

And now `dups` contains:

```
{frozenset({3, 4}), frozenset({3, 5}), frozenset({2, 6})}
```